# With react redux form, how can I style a hidden radio button's surrounding label?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

With react redux-form, I have the following form:

```
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field name="job_title_id" component={errorMessage} />
        {this.props.job_titles.map(jobTitle => (
        <div className="form-check" key={jobTitle.id}>
          <label className="btn btn-secondary">
            <Field
              name="job_title_id"
              component="input"
              type="radio"
              value={jobTitle.id}
              checked={this.props.job_titles.id}
            />
            {' '}
            {jobTitle.title}
          </label>
        </div>
        ))}
      </fieldset>
      <div className="form-group">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

For styling purposes, CSS is hiding the radio button. I need the field above the radio button know if the radio button is checked so I can add a class of ACTIVE to the label above:

if checked:

```
<label className="btn btn-secondary ACTIVE">
```

if not checked:

```
<label className="btn btn-secondary">
```

With react redux form, how can I style a hidden radio button's surrounding label?

Comment: Do you wanna now when the radio button is checked or uncheked? or when CSS is hiding the radio button? In which of this cases you wanna active the Label?

Comment: the css will always be hiding the radio button, but I need the label, to add the class of active when the radio button hidden within the label field is checked.

Comment: Did that answer the question? :)

Comment: Maybe. But I need more information. Who is the responsible for checked this radio button?

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand the q

Comment: When this radiobutton will be checked?

Comment: when a user clicks the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I get it.

The easy way to do that is keeping the radio checked status in state by onChange listener. So with this you put the class in the Label.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  ....  
  this.onRadioChange = this.onRadioChange.bind(this);

  this.state = {
    radioChecked: false
  }
}

onRadioChange (event) {
  this.setState({
    radioChecked: event.target.value
  });
}
....
<label className={(this.state.radioChecked ? "active": "" ) + " btn btn-secondary"}>
  <Field
    name="job_title_id"
    component="input"
    type="radio"
    value={jobTitle.id}
    checked={this.props.job_titles.id}
    onChange={this.onRadioChange}
  />
  {' '}
  {jobTitle.title}
</label>
....
```

I think this should works fine, even though I don't sure why you have to has a radiobutton, but ok :P.

Maybe there is a better solution using [Selecting Form Values Example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/selectingFormValues/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. This does work but seems to go outside of redux-form which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I agree. But, as I said, you can find a "redux solution" using Selecting Form Values Example.

Comment: shoot, turns out that doesn't work... the value from the redux solution returns the OLD value, not the most recently checked radio button

Comment: sad but true... can you find another way to do this without radio button?